# How to add files for custom module under system configuration?

Tags: module, admin, magento-1, xml, custom

I have my own module in System->Configuration and want to add js and css files for it. Now it is so:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name></action>
            <action method="addCss"><name>mymodule.css</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This way files added to all Admin pages. What to do to add this files just to one page, so write not default, but mymodule_admin or smth like that?

Comment: Question is marked as duplicate, but @fmrng gave best answer on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could uset the layout handle `adminhtml_system_config_edit` instead of `default`, and your files only under System > Configuration. The XML would look like this:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_system_config_edit>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name></action>
            <action method="addCss"><name>mymodule.css</name></action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_system_config_edit>
</layout>
```

If you only need these new files under a certail section, you should add your own layout handle, since Magento doesn't offer this out of the box. To be honest, I think this is not really worth the effort, but to answer your question:

**Add an event observer**

To achieve this, listen to the event `controller_action_layout_load_before`. In your `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <my_module_observer>
                        <class>my_module/observer</class>
                        <method>addCustomLayoutHandle</method>
                    </my_module_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
    <!-- ... -->
</config>
```

The event is thrown in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` in the method `loadLayoutUpdates()`.

**Add your custom layout handle**

Now that you have defined your event observer, you can check if the page you are currently on corresponds to the system configuration of your module. In your event observer:

```
public function addCustomLayoutHandle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getAction();
    $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
    if ($controllerAction && $layout && $controllerAction instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController) { // Can be checked in other ways of course
        if ($controllerAction->getRequest()->getParam('section') == 'my_module_section') {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('my_custom_handle');
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

The custom layout handle should be loaded now. You can use this new handle for your layout definition. Please not that I didn't have time to test this, hope it's working well. Just wanted to point you to a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: I know this, but I need to add files exactly to my module, not to all configuration pages. : )

Comment: I guess you'll have to add your layout handle dynamically using an event observer then. AFAIK there is no such standard layout handle, but it's quite easy to implement.

Comment: I'm new in backend functionality making, so not sure that it will be really easy, but will try. Thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer, have a look

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout handle name. Instead of `default` use the default handler for your page.
For example if your page url looks like this 'module/adminhtml_entity/index' (or `module/adminhtml_entity/` your layout can look like this:

```
<layout>
    <module_adminhtml_entity_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name></action>
            <action method="addCss"><name>mymodule.css</name></action>
        </reference>
    </module_adminhtml_entity_index>
</layout>
```

If your url looks like `admin/module_entity/index` your layout should look like this: (replace admin with adminhtml)

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_module_entity_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name></action>
            <action method="addCss"><name>mymodule.css</name></action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_module_entity_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: What if I have this url -> admin/system_config/edit/section/mymodule/key/.../ ?

Comment: then you can make the handle name like this `<adminhtml_system_config_edit>`. This means that the resources will be added for every section in the system->configuration section, but this shouldn't be a big issue. If you insist on having this only on your section, you can use an observer to add the resources, but I think you will work to much for nothing.